# Select all elements that have the same first three characters in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array

```
["Hello, how are you", "Hello, I'm well", "What is your name"]
```

I want to select all elements that have the same first three characters.  However, I don't know what the elements will be beforehand.

Edit:  Rethinking this question.  I'm really looking for a way to group elements that have the first x common characters.  They can either be new arrays or the same array, but the elements are sorted correctly.

Comment: How are you getting the 3 characters to look for?  Can you just run a regex filter over all elements in the array?

Comment: What is your expected output? It's unclear from your question

Comment: expected output would be new array that only has elements if they have common first 3 characters

Comment: What is the output for `["aaax", "aaay", "bbbz", "bbbw"]`?

Comment: I think the question is clear , he wants to find matching patterns ... The pattern is  to "elements of the array start with the same three chars "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely not clear what the OP wants, but if what the other answers at this moment give is what the OP wants, then here is a simpler way:

```
a = ["Hello, how are you", "Hello, I'm well", "What is your name"]
a.group_by{|e| e[0, 3]}
```

Comment: I up voted everyone's answer since they were all similar but this works the best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs clarifitcation- What if you have an array `["hello", "hello, what is your name?", "goodbye", "goodbye, user"]`?

In this case you would have 2 possible/mutually exclusive groups to select. I would approach this problem by avoiding #select all together:

-Create an empty `result` hash with a default return of a new, empty array.
-Iterate over each element in the array, pushing it onto the array at a key of its first three digits.
-Apply your choice of logic to return the hash or simply the key(s)/value(s) you want (max, all greater than 1, etc).

```
def first_three_chars_match(strings)
  result = Hash.new{ |hash,key| hash[key] = Array.new }
  strings.each do |string|
    key = string.slice(0,3)
    result[key] << string
  end
  result
end

first_three_chars_match(["hello", "hello, what is your name?", "goodbye", "goodbye, user"])
=> {"hel"=>["hello", "hello, what is your name?"], "goo"=>["goodbye", "goodbye, user"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this:

```
ary = ["Hello, how are you", "Hello, I'm well", "What is your name"]
matches = ary.inject({}) do |hash, str| 
  chars = str[0,3]; 
  hash[chars] = (hash[chars] || []) << str; 
  hash 
end
p matches
```

Output of program:

```
{"Hel"=>["Hello, how are you", "Hello, I'm well"], "Wha"=>["What is your name"]}
```